# Architectural reasons behind sitemeta, blogs, home, site and DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE redundancy

Tags: multisite

I have been using Wordpress around the time it came out, and the following settings have always puzzled me.

```
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);

wp_options.home
wp_options.siteurl

wp_site
wp_blogs

wp_sitemeta.siteurl
```

How do they relate to each other? What are their different uses within Wordpress? What is the processing architecture behind? Are there any drawings? Why do we need (at least) 5 similar variables to just denote where the website is at?

In all those years never have I found any decent explanation. The internet is riddled with do-this-and-do-thats, mostly by people who have no idea what they are talking about.

Someone with enough Wordpress development experience to clarify this?

Comment: Blog ID only applies on MultiSite - it references which of the various subsites you're working on. Typically redundancies are for backwards compatibility - WP has over the years striven to not break previous versions, so many less efficient things have been mostly replaced by more efficient ones - but the less efficient ones left in place to support sites who haven't taken the time to update.

Comment: Those aren't always the same, nor do they represent the same thing

Answer (score 3):

## How do they relate to each other? What are their different uses within Wordpress?

> define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
>
> define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');

These 2 are not the same thing, e.g. for a WP site whose root is at example.com/wp `DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE` will be `example.com`, and `PATH_CURRENT_SITE` will be `/wp`

> define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
>
> define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);

Site != blog. In a multisite you can have multiple blogs, so `BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE` represents the current blog. `1` being the first blog or root blog.

Site ID on the other hand refers to the network. Networks have no UI, and a multisite install in 99% of cases has a single network. There is some confusion about terminology, hence site not network

> wp_options.home
>
> wp_options.siteurl

Home URL is the homepage of the site, but that doesn't mean the same thing as the sites URL, the two are almost always the same, but they can be different

> wp_site
>
> wp_blogs

These tables store different things. Blogs are stored in `wp_blogs`, and `wp_site` lists the networks those blogs belong to. As I mentioned before sites have a single network unless you specifically set out to add more

> wp_sitemeta.siteurl

The sites table contains a domain and path, this is a more complete version. This table also has other information, such as who is the network admin etc

## What is the processing architecture behind?

Networks contain blogs, blogs contain posts.

E.g. .org is a multisite install, as it wordpress.com.

Networks allow you to have multiple multisites on the same install. This way 2 multisites can share the same users and code yet users of 1 multisite never see anything of the other. This might be so that local school authorities can give schools blogs, but administer separately.

The use cases of networks are rare, and can also be accomplished in many cases by several multisite installs with SSO

## Are there any drawings?

Probably but I doubt it'd be as helpful as you'd think. Check the table scheme wiki page on the codex

## Why do we need (at least) 5 similar variables to just denote where the website is at?

Because they don't denote the same things, and they just happen to have the same values when on a single site. It's rare that they diverge but they can and do.

Also some of them do not store the same thing as the others